# Refresh/Regenerate Linkedin OAuth User Token and OAuth User Secret in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, access-token

The OAuth User Token and OAuth User Secret actually expires in 60 days. 
I looked at this [link](http://developer.linkedin.com/blog/tips-and-tricks-refreshing-access-token), but in my case this is not helpful.

What actually I do in my app:

I use oauth gem for authorization as below.

```
@linkedin_consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(
                    API_KEY,
                    SECRET_KEY,
                    { :site => "https://api.linkedin.com" }
                    )
linkedin_access_token = OAuth::AccessToken.new(@linkedin_consumer,OAUTH_USER_TOKEN, OAUTH_USER_SECRET)
```

Now by using linkedin_access_token I make api calls to get profile data. I get only linkedin id from the users, I never ask user to login in linkedin.com. So, how can I refresh it. please reply ASAP. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No endpoints for refreshing linkedin OAuth2.0 Tokens have been mentioned anywhere in their documentation yet. All they say is:

> Provided that the user is already logged into LinkedIn, this flow
>   provides you with a simple way of obtaining a valid OAuth 2.0 access
>   token without forcing your user to authorize your application again

But having user logged into LinkedIn wont really solve the purpose of refreshing tokens in backend. OAuth1.0 does have a mechanism mentioned.

One useful discussion on this topic I found : [here](http://developer.linkedin.com/forum/how-refresh-oauth2-token)